# Running bash command using exclamation mark not working with python prompt

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

I was trying to run below command but getting invalid syntax error

```
$python
python 3.7.4
linux
>>> !ls
 File "<stdin>", line 1
   !ls
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>exit()
```

Comment: Because it is an [`IPython` feature](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html#python-vs-ipython)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the [shell assignment](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html#shell-assignment) feature of ***IPython***, *not* a core part of Python itself. The fact that you don't see the `In [1]:` style of prompts (you have `>>>`) means that you're *not* running IPython.

---

If you want to run a shell command from "normal" Python, the usual approach is with something like:

```
import os
os.system("whatever")
```

Just keep in mind the shell assignment feature is a tad more powerful than that.

---

If you need that feature, and you have IPython correctly installed, just run `ipython` instead of `python`.

Answer (score 1):

if you are running it in jupyter notebook, it should work.

Based on the code, it shows you are running it on command prompt or shell.

if you are running it in command or shell prompt the Exclamatory symbol didnt work.

Try this approach

```
import os
os.system('ls')
```